# Windows Phone 8 global application bar localization

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to create a localized windows phone 8 app , and I am creating a global application bar . However I am unable to set the text of the items inside the bar using the resource , anyone have an idea how to do that ? I am also unable to get it in code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reuse the commented code in the template's MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
{
  // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
  ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

  // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from AppResources.
 ApplicationBarIconButton appBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/appbar.add.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
 //Search in AppResources.Search is a key of a string in the resource files (.resx)
 appBarButton.Text = AppResources.Search;
 ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButton);

 // Create a new menu item with the localized string from AppResources.
 //Search in AppResources.Search is a key of a string in the resource files (.resx)
 ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarMenuItem = new ApplicationBarMenuItem(AppResources.Search);
 ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarMenuItem);
}
```

unfortunately the app bar is not a traditional Silverlight control so you have to create programmatically in every page if you want it localized.